# Stack overflow somewhere in an IIS7 C# ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, stack-overflow

My website's IIS7 worker process (w3wp.exe) is being restarted every couple of minutes due to a stack overflow exception which is happening somewhere in a medium-large application.

Event viewer doesn't provide any details as to where the error occurs in the code.

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to stack overflow.
```

**There's no stack trace** in the event viewer from which to find the where the error is. There are no specific recursive functions in the code (afaik), there probably are indirect recursions, e.g. A calling B calling C calling A.

How do I go on about finding where the faulty code is? I can't debug with Visual Studio because it only happens on the production server with hundreds of users accessing the website.

Comment: A common source of stack overflow exceptions is properties. E.g. the getter returns the getter property instead of the underlying variable.

Comment: In that case I suppose it would happen immediately rather than statistically and I would've been able to reproduce it on a development machine.

Comment: I would assume that too, I was just pointing it out as a comment to your observation about no recursive functions.

Comment: DON'T USE REMOTE DEBUGGER. Instal VisualStudio. remote debugger wasted one week of my time with it's poor design. For example You should have a user with the same username/password on both machines for debugging which is not documented well anywhere.

Comment: I use remote debugger all the time and it works well.  I agree that the fact that you can debug across domains by useing the same username and password is not well documented but that is not a oproblem with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio debugger will catch it.

Comment: It only happens in production with hundreds of users accessing the website.

Comment: You can [attach to the process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx) using the [remote debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Comment: That would require installing Visual Studio on a Win2008 production server.

Comment: On the basis that you are getting a stack overflow every 2 minutes killing the iis worker process i would say debugging on the live server is the least of your worries.  You will only be doing it for a couple of minutes until the exception is thrown and then you can detatch.  I can't imaging that will cause any more disruption to users than they are getting now with iis WP restarting every couple of minutes.

Comment: @Liam to use the remote debugger you just need the remote debugger on the server not Visual Studio, the remote debugger is a tiny .net app that does not require installation.  You will nee some kind of VPN or other network connection from you VS PC to the server though.

Comment: It's not the disruption, it's installing VS2010 Express on the server.. but goddammit you're right and those other memory dump tools look very nasty. Installing VS2010 Express on the server now.

Comment: I suppose it should be VWD2010

Comment: @Ben Thanks I won't bother with setting up the VPN I'll just go ahead and install VS on the server.

Comment: Can't install it ffs it says it depends on Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact which itself depends on Visual Web Developer 2010 SP1

Comment: Okay VS debugger catches it but still no stack trace :S

Comment: No you won't get a stack trace that wasn't the point, wherever in the code that the debugger caatches the exception is where the exception happens.  Try updating you question with the line of code where the debugger catches the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `windbg`. Use `adplus` to get a crash dump:

- [Back to Basics - How do I get the memory dumps in the first place? And what is SOS.dll?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/01/11/511773.aspx)